# Read only new files from a folder

Tags: rstudio

In Rstudio I am trying to read csv-format data files from a folder where new files are being added continuously. I want to read only the new files every 10 minutes.

How can I write code that checks the folder for new files every few minutes and reads only those files from that folder?